# How to check if the file is having the same type as of its extension?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, file-type

I want to build Javascript code which checks for the file type.In the web application which I am creating allows user to upload document files `viz`, `doc`, `xls`, `ppt`, `docx`, `xlsx`, `pptx`, `txt`, `rar`, `zip`, `pdf`, `jpg`, `png`, `gif`, `jpeg`, `odt`, but it should not allow other files. I can't check just extension name in file name. As user may change it.

I tried checking content-type but it is also getting changed everytime. Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "modern" browsers (IE10+, Firefox 4+, Chrome 7+, Safari 6.0.2+ etc.), you *could* use the `File`/`FileReader` API to read the contents of the file and parse it client-side. E.g. (example, not production code):

```js
var fileInput = /* Your <input type="file"> element */

fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = fileLoaded;
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});

function fileLoaded(e)
{
   var arrayBuffer = e.currentTarget.result;

   // 32 indicates that we just want a look at the first 32 bytes of the buffer.
   // If we don't specify a length, we get the entire buffer.
   var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer, 0, 32);

   // Now we can check the content, comparing to whatever file signatures we
   // have, e.g.:

   if (bytes[0] == 0x50 &&
       bytes[1] == 0x4b &&
       bytes[2] == 0x03 &&
       bytes[3] == 0x04)
   {
      // This is most likely docx, xlsx, pptx or other zip file.
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35XfG/

Note, however, that e.g. a .zip doesn't *have* to start with 50 4b 03 04. So, unless you spend quite a bit of time looking into different file signatures (or find some library that already did this), you're likely to be rejecting files that might actually be valid. Of course, it's also possible that it will give false positives.

False positives don't matter that much in this case, though - because this is only useful as a user friendly measure to check that the user isn't uploading files that will be rejected by the server anyway. The server should *always* validate what it ends up getting sent.

Of course, reading the entire file to look at the first few bytes isn't all that efficient either. :-) See Ray Nicholus' comment about that.

Comment: `file.slice(0,4);`  then send that through `FileReader`

Comment: I have tried this method. It looks like this is what i wanted. But the same is not working for me.I have checked this site also. Are you sure value which we are reading is in hex? Thanks for your solution by the way.
http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Comment: Sorry, slight bug (did say it wasn't production code - didn't say that it wasn't tested either, but posted for inspiration more than an example to follow) :-) Missed an argument to the `Uint8Array` constructor - second parameter is the start offset, *third* is the length. Added a JSFiddle to demonstrate (with the correct code).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can actually parse the content and by the results tell whether the file is of a certain type, I don't see a good way of doing that with pure JS. You might want to consider to upload the file to the sever temporarily, and then perform the check on the server. The unix file command is a very useful tool for that. It does not rely on file extensions, but uses the file content to analyze the file type.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is really helpful. But I want to save server load and want to perform this operation at client side only. Would you please suggest me in this direction.

Comment: When you want to avoid users uploading tampered files (other content than the extension suggests), you should definitely do that on the server side. The client side can easily be tampered with. When you still want to so it on the client side, I suggest you identify certain pieces of content that must be contained in each file of a certain type or patterns. Then you could check against these patterns. Still, as a security measure, pure client side validation is a bad idea.